# expected a declaration. syntax error: ','

Tags: c++

```
#pragma once
#include <ctime>
#include "lib.h"

class testtime
{
public:
    int start_s = 0,stop_s = 0;
    void starttesttime(){
        start_s = clock();
        stop_s = 0;
    },
    stoptesttime(std::string t){
        stop_s = clock();
        std::cout << t << " time: " << (stop_s - start_s) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << std::endl;
        start_s = 0;
    };
};
```

I got the Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

```
Error (active)  E0169   expected a declaration  test    c:\Users\AWW\Desktop\test\test\testtime.h   12 .  
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2059   syntax error: ','   test    c:\users\aww\desktop\test\test\testtime.h   12  
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2334   unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body  test    c:\users\aww\desktop\test\test\testtime.h   13
```

I really declare the code. Not really sure

Comment: typo: the keys that close the implementation of a function should not be followed by a semicolon. `}; <---
};`, see the last line of your code.

Comment: Also, they should not be followed by a comma:  `},`  bad comma, no biscuit!

Comment: void testtime(),
 ~testtime(); <- no error

Comment: @WeiWen 
When only a function is declared, the semicolon is valid and mandatory, but when you implement it, it is not, I recommend you to look for a good IDE so that you do not fall into these simple and foolish problems.

Comment: void starttesttime(),
 stoptesttime(std::string t); <- no error because is not a function. if is void starttesttime(){},
 stoptesttime(std::string t){};<- is wrong ??

Comment: There is absolutely nothing to be gained from declaring multiple things in one declaration. And for functions it just makes declarations unreadable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ it is OK to have several comma-separated function *declarators* in one declaration, even when you are declaring class member functions

```
struct S
{
  void foo(), bar(int) const, baz(double, char);
};

/* Same as
struct S
{
  void foo();
  void bar(int) const;
  void baz(double, char);
};
*/
```

However, making several comma-separated function *definitions* in one declaration is not allowed

```
struct S
{
  void foo() {}, bar(int) const {}, baz(double, char) {}; // ERROR
};
```

Function definition is not a declarator.

Your code suffers from that problem specifically. You are trying to *define* two `void` functions in one declaration. You have to define them independently - each definition shall be a separate declaration.

Comment: thank for simple and clear answer